# Find Matrix $B$ s.t $Rowspan(A)=Rowspan(B)$ And $(1,1,1)\in Columnspan(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & 0 & 3 \\
> 2 & 1 & 5 \\
> -1 & 2 &-5 
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> Find a matrix $B$ such that $Rowspan(A)=Rowspan(B)$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 
> 1  \\
> 1  \\
> 1 
> \end{pmatrix}\in Columnspan(B)$

So to find $Rowspan(A)$ I row reduced $\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & 5 \\
-1 & 2 &-5 
\end{pmatrix}$ to  $\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}$ and because row operations do not change the row span so $B$ should span the same space of $CF(A)$ and  $\begin{pmatrix} 
1  \\
1  \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}\in Columnspan(B)$

But where should I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here

$$A^{RREF}=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

you are done, indeed just consider

$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 &3 
\end{pmatrix}$$

and note that $$B\cdot (1,1,0)=(1,1,1)$$